# How can I copy contacts from Google Apps for Business Directory to another Google Mail account?

Tags: contacts, google-contacts, google-apps-email

I don't really understand how Google Apps for domains directories work.  When I start an email it knows about all the people at my domain, but when I go to Contacts, I can't find a directory of just those people.

I would like to export them to my personal Gmail account.

(more details: I have two Google Apps accounts and a Gmail account and I'm trying to consolidate them all so I can just check one location.  Not having those directories available to email to makes things difficult.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are the admin of the Google Apps account you could go to **Organizations & users** and from **More actions**: **Download as CSV**.

Once you've done that then you can easily modify the file as Google [wants](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=12119) it and then import them as usual.

Comment: But unfortunately, this method does not sync photos!

Answer (score 2):

I can't find a way to just see the people from your domain, but it's possible you could search for them using the domain or company name?

Once you've managed to get them all selected (which might be tedious, but is the only hard part) you can then click More Actions -> Export and choose to export the selected contacts as a CSV.

In the other account, just click More Actions -> Import and locate the CSV. Don't forget to run More Actions -> Find & Merge Duplicates afterwards, in case you already had some with slightly different details.

Comment: Seems like the only hacky way to do it.  Thanks for the tip on searching for domain.